# To be assigned value as variable in jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

[json processor jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for a package.json

```
{
  "someparent" : {
    "somechild" : "oldvalue"
  }
}
```

If I run the following command (to change `oldvalue` to `somevalue`):

```
jq '.someparent["somechild"] = "somevalue" "$aDirection/package.json"'
```

It is successfully changed. However, if I give a variable instead of `someValue`:

```
 aVar="anotherValue"
 jq '.someparent["somechild"] = "$aVar" "$aDirection/package.json"'
```

It is not working.
What I already tried:

```
["aVar"] #interpreted as string
["$aVar"] #interpreted as string
"$aVar" # aVar is not defined
$avar #aVar is not defined
```

Comment: I had seen that question but their answers don't fit this situation and also didn't work (e.g. `\"aVar\"`)

Comment: @BenjaminW. the question can be seen like a duplicate for an expert user but it is absolutely not for beginners, qua type, qua solution and handled method. ps: as you said, json had just simplifying problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The single quotes around the `jq` filter are in  the wrong place. In your attempt made it is also enclosing the actual JSON file input. The right syntax when applying filter over files is

```
jq '<filter>' json-file
```

In your case the right filter is just

```
.someparent["somechild"] = $aVar
```

and to use a shell variable in to the `jq`, you need to use the `--arg` field. Putting together both of the options. The first variable after `--arg` is used in the context of `jq` and the one following it is the actual shell variable.

```
aVar="anotherValue"
jq --arg aVar "$aVar" '.someparent["somechild"] = $aVar' "$aDirection/package.json"
#                                                    ^^^^ Remember the single quote 
#                                                    terminating here and not extended
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear: using the OP's approach can be made to work, e.g.

```
jq '.someparent["somechild"] = "'"$aVar"'"' "$aDirection/package.json"
```

but using `--arg` (for strings) and/or `--argjson` is far better.  An additional option for environment variables is to use the jq function `env`.